# How to convert List<string> to JSon format in C#

Tags: c#, json

I have a List of string that contains the below items:

- 001-HA-Manager
- 001-HA-Supervisor
- 001-HA-Validation
- 001-HA-DocumentReviewer
- 001-HA-ManagerReviewer
- 002-HA-Manager
- 002-HA-Supervisor
- 002-HA-Validation

I need to those item on the below JSON format:

```
{
"Project": [
  {
    "ProjectCode": "001",
    "Groups": ["Manager", "Supervisor", "Validation", "DocumentReviewer","ManagerReviewer"]
  },
  {
     "ProjectCode": "002",
     "Groups": ["Manager", "Supervisor", "Validation"]
    }
]
```

}de here

Comment: What have you tried? Please share some code and explain what is not working.

Answer (score 1):

you can try this code

```
    string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject( new
    {
    Project = list.Select(l => l.Split("-"))
                  .Select(l => new { Key = l[0], Value = l[2] })
                  .GroupBy(g => g.Key, g => g.Value)
                  .Select(g => new { ProjectCode = g.Key, Groups = g })
    }, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented);
```

Answer (score 1):

Using a traditional approach without any one liners. I have created corresponding `Model` classes to hold your data and the tokenize it as required to fill out the respective fields into the `Model` class:

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/XH28FX

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        List<string> input=new List<string>();
        input.Add("001-HA-Manager");
        input.Add("001-HA-Supervisor");
        input.Add("001-HA-Validation");
        input.Add("001-HA-DocumentReviewer");
        input.Add("001-HA-ManagerReviewer");
        input.Add("002-HA-Manager");
        input.Add("002-HA-Supervisor");
        input.Add("002-HA-Validation");
        
        List<Lookup> lookup= new List<Lookup>();
        foreach(var item in input)
        {
            Lookup lookupitem=new Lookup();
            var tokenizeditem=item.Split('-');
            lookupitem.ProjectCode=tokenizeditem[0];
            lookupitem.Title=tokenizeditem[2];
            lookup.Add(lookupitem); 
        }
        
        //Now group by:
        var test= from p in lookup
              group p.Title by p.ProjectCode into g
              select new Project { ProjectCode = g.Key, Groups = g.ToList() };
        var customDataObj = new { Project = test };
        var jstring= JsonConvert.SerializeObject(customDataObj);
        Console.WriteLine(jstring); 
    }
}

public class Project
{
    public string ProjectCode {get;set;}
    public List<string> Groups {get;set;}
}

public class Lookup
{
    public string ProjectCode {get;set;}
    public string Title {get;set;}
}
```

Output: `{"Project":[{"ProjectCode":"001","Groups":["Manager","Supervisor","Validation","DocumentReviewer","ManagerReviewer"]},{"ProjectCode":"002","Groups":["Manager","Supervisor","Validation"]}]}`

After validating from [Jsonlint](https://jsonlint.com/):
[image]

Answer (score 0):

First create class

then ,define a constructor to receive the data and then separate the project and the group And then  group the project and create Jason

I use Newtonsoft.Json and Linq

1.create class

```
 public class MyDate
        {
            public MyDate(string All)
            {
                this.All = All;
            }
            public string ProjectCode
            {
                get { return this.All.Split('-')[0]; }
            }

            public string Group
            {
                get { return this.All.Split('-')[2]; }
            }
           
            public string All { set; get; }
        }
```

2.Add data

```
  List< MyDate> _li = new List<MyDate> 
{ new MyDate("001-HA-Manager"), new MyDate("001-HA-Validation"),
           new MyDate("001-HA-Supervisor"),
new MyDate("001-HA-Validation"),
new MyDate("001-HA-DocumentReviewer")
           ,new MyDate("001-HA-ManagerReviewer") 
 ,new MyDate("002-HA-Manager") 
 ,new MyDate("002-HA-Supervisor")
            ,new MyDate("002-HA-Validation")
           };
```

3.group by with linq and create json

```
 var listall = _li
          .GroupBy(d => d.ProjectCode)
           .Select(g => new {
            ProjectCode = g.Key,
          Groups = g.Select(d => d.Group)
     }).ToList();
     
var jsonString = "{\r\n\"Project\":" + JsonConvert.SerializeObject(listall , Formatting.Indented) + "}";
```